# Como criar variável global no php?

Tags: codeigniter, variáveis, variáveis-globais

Estou trabalhando com o framework do codeigniter completamente separado do front-end. Ou seja, executo as regras de negócios e emito um json no controller. No entanto, estou fazendo uma autenticação para permitir se o usuário receberá o dado, ou não. Como não há a possibilidade de usar session, pensei em usar um variável global que retorna true ou false. Dessa forma, posso verificar se o usuário está logado, e tenho essa variável em toda a aplicação. Como faço uma variável global no codeigniter?

Comment: Você pode usar o MY_Controller, com ele você põe a função de verificação lá. E no seu construct, você chama a função. $this->nome_funcao_executar();

Comment: Você pode postar o código do que tentou fazer?

Comment: Você pode usar através de uma classe, e fazer um `public "nome_da_variável"`

Comment: Redis, JWT, banco de dados, cookie. Já tentou qualquer um desses? Mostre a autenticação que está fazendo, facilita a resposta.